# Jogar uma classe html dentro de um código asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery

Tenho esse código:

```
<%# Eval("DsPathDocumento") != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DsPathDocumento").ToString()) ? String.Concat("href='/UpLoads/", Eval("DsPathDocumento"), "'") : "style='cursor: default; color:#000000;'" %>>
```

Como eu faria para jogar essa classe: `class="linkUpload"` dentro da primeira condição da expressão ternária? Ou seja, gostaria de apenas a parte após o "?" pegasse essa classe para que a minha função jquery pudesse rodar.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.linkUpload').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow", "scrollbars=yes");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi assim:

```
<strong><a <%# Eval("DsPathDocumento") != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DsPathDocumento").ToString()) ? String.Concat("href='/UpLoads/", Eval("DsPathDocumento"), "'","class='linkUpload'") : "style='cursor: default; color:#000000;' class='disabled'" %>>
                        <%# Eval("NmTipoDocumento") %>
                    </a></strong>
```